# "She suggested me to go shopping."

Tags: grammar

I wrote "She suggested me to go shopping." Why is it wrong?

Can we say one of the following sentences?

1. She suggested going shopping.
2. She suggested that we to go shopping.

How would you correct my original sentence?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: *She suggested that we go shopping* is grammatical.  You have to eliminate the "to".

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Suggest to go" vs. "suggest going"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124904/suggest-to-go-vs-suggest-going). Or more precisely, [How to use the word “suggest” correctly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209287/), but that one has no upvoted answers.

Comment: The "we went" is, I think a subjunctive and is made perhaps more clear be changing "she suggested" to "she proposed" or "she insisted". I don't think that the "we had gone" possibility exists.

Comment: The closest, correct phrase would be *she suggested that I go shopping* or *she suggested that we go shopping*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only correct is "1". "She suggested our going shopping" or "She suggested that we went shopping" are the two grammatically correct forms to include both parties.

Comment: Why to use 'our'? Is it possible to use'us'?
-
She suggested us going shopping.

Comment: "Us" is probably used colloquially, but the possesive is probably more correct before a gerund.

Comment: To many people (myself included), “She suggested that we went shopping” is not correct in the sense intended here. It means roughly “She suggested that we had gone shopping”. If she was making a suggestion of what to do, the subjunctive is required for many speakers still: “She suggested that we go shopping”.

Comment: This is clearly a BrE answer. Many (I suspect most) Americans would never say *"she suggested that we went shopping"*; it sounds completely ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @Peter To me, the distinction I mentioned above holds in BrE as well. “… that we should go” would be an alternative to the subjunctive in BrE, but the past tense is not.

Comment: @Janus: [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suggested+that+we+should+go%3A+eng_us_2012%2Csuggested+that+we+should+go%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Csuggested+that+we+went%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Csuggested+that+we+went%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuggested%20that%20we%20should%20go%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuggested%20that%20we%20should%20go%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuggested%20that%20we%20went%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuggested%20that%20we%20went%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Peter And adding the subjunctive to that shows that it is still far more common than any other variant.

Comment: @Janus: Maybe *"suggested that we went ..."* isn't yet grammatical in BrE, but it's clearly much less ungrammatical than it is in AmE.

Comment: @Peter It's perfectly grammatical (in both BrE and AmE), it just means something else. And yes, it's also encroaching upon the meaning relevant here in BrE, but much less than the _should_ variant, which is more or less universal in BrE.